# How to solve the following Frobenius norm-minimization problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, nonlinear-programming, least-squares, matrix-equations

## Background

We know how to solve the following minimization problem

$$
\min_{X} \lVert AX - B \rVert_F^2
$$

## But what about the extended version?

$$
\min_{X} \lVert A
\begin{bmatrix}
X & X^2 
\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}
B_1 & B_2 
\end{bmatrix} \rVert_F^2
$$

Is there any analytical solution to this? Or we have to use gradient descent like method?

Comment: This doesn't look like a generalization but a quadratic problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\big\| \mathrm A \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm X & \mathrm X^2\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm B_1 & \mathrm B_2\end{bmatrix} \big\|_{\text{F}}^2 = \underbrace{\| \mathrm A \mathrm X - \mathrm B_1 \|_{\text{F}}^2}_{=: f_1 (\mathrm X)} + \underbrace{\| \mathrm A \mathrm X^2 - \mathrm B_2 \|_{\text{F}}^2}_{=: f_2 (\mathrm X)}$$

Everybody knows that

$$\nabla f_1 (\mathrm X) = 2 \, \mathrm A^\top \big( \mathrm A \, \mathrm X - \mathrm B_1 \big)$$

The challenge is to compute $\nabla f_2 (\mathrm X)$. Since $f_2$ is quartic in $\mathrm X$, the gradient $\nabla f_2$ should be cubic.

$$f_2 (\mathrm X + h \mathrm V) = \cdots = f_2 (\mathrm X) + 2 h \, \mbox{tr} \big( \left( \mathrm X \mathrm V + \mathrm V \mathrm X \right)^\top \mathrm A^\top \left( \mathrm A \mathrm X^2 - \mathrm B_2 \right) \big) + o (h^2)$$

Computing the **directional derivative** of $f_2$ in the direction of $\mathrm V$ at $\mathrm X$,

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f_2 (\mathrm X + h \mathrm V) - f_2 (\mathrm X)}{h} = 2 \, \mbox{tr} \big( \left( \mathrm X \mathrm V + \mathrm V \mathrm X \right)^\top \mathrm A^\top \left( \mathrm A \mathrm X^2 - \mathrm B_2 \right) \big)$$

Extracting the **gradient** $\nabla f_2 (\mathrm X)$ from the (Frobenius) inner product,

$$\boxed{\nabla f_2 (\mathrm X) = 2 \, \mathrm X^\top \mathrm A^\top \big( \mathrm A \,\mathrm X^2 - \mathrm B_2 \big) + 2 \, \mathrm A^\top \big( \mathrm A \,\mathrm X^2 - \mathrm B_2 \big) \mathrm X^\top}$$

which is indeed cubic in $\rm X$. Using the [anticommutator](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Anticommutator.html),

$$\nabla f_2 (\mathrm X) = \big\{ \mathrm X^\top, 2 \, \mathrm A^\top \big( \mathrm A \,\mathrm X^2 - \mathrm B_2 \big) \big\}$$

Comment: So what's the answer to OP's question *Is there any analytical solution to this? Or we have to use gradient descent like method?*

Comment: @FedericoPoloni You're the expert on matrix equations! I took it as far as my knowledge goes, which is not that far. I assume that the cubic matrix equation is very hard to solve, for some rank-constrained problems I encountered in the past reduced to cubic matrix equations.

Comment: I'm thinking about that, but I don't know of a closed-form solution on the top of my head (or I would have written an answer / comment). I was just pointing out that it's useful to have the gradient computed explicitly, but that's not what OP was asking. :)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Gradient descent is an option only if the cost function is convex. However, [deciding whether quartic polynomials are convex is NP-hard](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.1908).